# What do the to/from fields in a swap event mean?

Tags: web3js, events

Im parsing swap log events from web3 and was reading the to and from addresses from the topic but sometimes the from/to address is the same, and other times its different.  It doesn't seem to ever be the pair address which I thought one of them (to/from) would always be.

Can someone explain this to me in more detail?